# How do I extract anthocyanin from a blueberry?

Tags: extraction

I am doing a school project to extract anthocyanin from a fruit. I chose blueberry. What is a step by step method to extract the anthocyanin? I have to do it in school so hopefully its not a very complex procedure. Also, im not allowed to use methonal as it is flammable. From what i have researched, i should use ethanol and hydrochloric acid. But i do not know what else to add. Thank you.

Comment: Huh?!? Ethanol is flammable too...

Comment: In what form do you want them to be obtained? To do what ? Because depending on the purpose, we can proceed through more or less complex experiments ...

Comment: Ethanol/water, HCl procedure here - though whether you can do it as described depends on how well equipped you school lab is. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276264844_Optimal_Extraction_of_Pure_Anthocyanins_from_Fruits_of_Sambucus_nigra

Comment: @Nicolas Im obtaining the anthocyanin to conduct a kinetic study to explore the antioxidant properties of the extracted anthocyanin

Comment: @MaxW actually im not too sure why we are not allowed to use methanol. Maybe the school just does not have it

Comment: Methanol is a lot more toxic than ethanol, which is probably the reason.

Comment: @Waylander so i crush/blend the blueberries and add 70% ethanol-water 1%citric/hydrochloric acid. After that what is the extraction process? I filtrate the solution with filter paper and obtain the filtrate, mix it with silica gel, filtrate again and then heat up the filtrate to get rid of the ethanol. Lastly i purify it by adding silica gel, acetic acid and ethyl acetate. I dont have to filtrate the solution again or heat it up to get rid of the silica gel, acetic acid and ethyl acetate? Also it says that i add acetic acid to remove water soluble compounds, but isnt anthocyanin watee soluble?

Comment: Anthocyanins are hot water souble but note the specification of the silica quoted in the procedure - it is reverse phase silica.